# How to change checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

change value of checkbox doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
$(document).change('add',function() { 
    $(".activateuploadedpic").click(function(){
        if ($(this).val()=='true') {
            $(this).attr('value','false');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('value','true');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to this:

```js
$(".activateuploadedpic").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="false" class="activateuploadedpic" />
```